# pubspec.yaml file has a newer timestamp

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using flutter to develop a previously created project. I have copied the project from another PC and copied it into my laptop. I have opened the project with vs code and in terminal I ran flutter packages get and after that when I ran flutter run I got this error  `pub did not update .packages file (pubspec.yaml file has a newer timestamp)` 
any ideas?

Comment: Try deleting the `.packages` file and run `flutter packages get` again.

Comment: still getting the error @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Try editing `pubspec.yaml` with some bogus change and try again. Also ensure your system time/date is set properly.

Comment: it solved my problem. thank you @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 7):

Try editing `pubspec.yaml` with some bogus change and try again. Also ensure your system time/date is set properly.

Comment: What do mean by "bogus change"?

Comment: Some random change, then save the file and undo the random change. Just to get the file modified and the modified times of the file updated.